# How to fill a dataframe at specific index and column by iterating over rows of another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `user_follow` that looks like this..

```
followerId  followingId

abc1998     abc1997
abc1998     abc1991
abc1998     abc1992
abc1998     abc1994
abc1998     abc1995
abc1998     abc1996
abc1998     abc2035
```

The 'followerId' and 'followingId' are ID of various users. I have another list `uniqueUsers` that has a list o almost 100 total users.

I have created a dataframe `df` with all 0 values and indices and rows as elements of `uniqueUsers`.

```
          abc2003 abc2022 abc2023 ... abc1997 abc1998 abc2035 abc1996   
abc2003     0       0       0     ...   0       0       0        0
abc2022     0       0       0     ...   0       0       0        0
abc2023     0       0       0     ...   0       0       0        0
abc2024     0       0       0     ...   0       0       0        0
abc2027     0       0       0     ...   0       0       0        0
.
.
.
```

So, the above dataframe has 100 rows and 100 columns.

I want to fill the above dataframe `df` by iterating through the dataframe `user_follow`. For every (followerId, followingId) from `user_follow`, I want to fill '1' in the corresponding (row,column) of the above dataframe `df`.  Here, row/index and columns are the unique users from `uniqueUsers` list.

Any help on this?

Comment: Do you want to fill the values of the table (100,100) with 1 if the user in row follows the user in col ? Btw, iteration on tables or data frames are not effective solutions, think of a vectorized solution rather.

Comment: No. I want to fill 1 in the (100 x 100) dataframe for every user pair I get from the ```user_follow``` dataframne i.e. I want to fill 1 for ('abc1998', 'abc1997') , ('abc1998', 'abc1991'), ('abc1998', 'abc1992,) and so on.

The user_follow table also has many entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how you want the output table, but probably the following does the trick. Simply try this:

```
output_table = pd.crosstab(user_follow.followerId, user_follow.followingId)
```

Alternatively for more complex fillings, you can use `iterrows` method of `pd.DataFrame` as

```
for i, row in user_follow.iterrows():
     # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to update the uniqueuser dataframe you can do it this way:

```
for row in user_follow.itertuples():
    uniqueuser.loc[row[1]][row[2]] = 1
```